WordPress homepage shows default theme after migration – logged-out users see different content
I migrated a website from Enom to Hostinger, installed wordpress to the website, and uploaded my backup files using Updraft.
When I am logged in as an admin, everything works just fine. But when i try to access the homepage from another browser/device, while logged out, it displays the "Twenty twenty-four theme's default page"
I use the "Astra" theme. Every other page(url) on the website works just fine. The only issue is the homepage which displays the wrong information when i try to access it while logged-out



The Theme setting issue after migration. Here are a few steps you can follow:
This issue is WordPress side if migrated WordPress theme and settings are removed or reset.
Homepage Settings: Go to Settings → Reading in the WordPress dashboard and ensure that your homepage is set to display a specific page or the latest posts, as per your setup. Kindly Make sure it's pointing to the correct homepage.
WordPress Theme Settings: Go to Appearance → Customize, and ensure that the Astra theme is active and configured correctly for the homepage. There might be theme-specific settings affecting the homepage for logged-out users.
Permalink Settings: Sometimes, permalink settings show issues after migration. Go to Settings → Permalinks, and without changing anything, click Save Changes to refresh the permalink structure.
File and Database Issues: Check if all theme files were properly migrated. Clear Browser and Server Cache.
Please follow these steps should help resolve the issue of wrong homepage content.
